# How to delete a file which have such type of extensions in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, unlink

What I'm trying to do is, to delete files which includes only such type of extensions.

Let's say a folder `Images/` contains following files,

```
a.jpg
b.jpeg
c.php
d.php2
c.png
```

So now I want to delete only those `c.php,d.php2`. Is there any way to do this in a single step or any ideas ?

**Note:** In this case, I do not know exact name of the **file** or **extension**.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can iterate over a directory and then check each files name with a regex for a match (assuming you have a pattern).

Comment: Hi chris,If I have more than 1000 images in a folder and I decided to put a cron for every hour, will it affect the perfomance ?

Comment: I don't think so, I'd do tests to confirm that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete specific extension files from sub directories, you can use the following function. Example:

```
<?php 
function delete_recursively_($path,$match){
   static $deleted = 0,
   $dsize = 0;
   $dirs = glob($path."*");
   $files = glob($path.$match);
   foreach($files as $file){
      if(is_file($file)){
         $deleted_size += filesize($file);
         unlink($file);
         $deleted++;
      }
   }
   foreach($dirs as $dir){
      if(is_dir($dir)){
         $dir = basename($dir) . "/";
         delete_recursively_($path.$dir,$match);
      }
   }
   return "$deleted files deleted with a total size of $deleted_size bytes";
}
?>
```

e.g. To remove all text files you can use it as follows:

```
<?php echo delete_recursively_('/home/username/directory/', '.txt'); ?>
```